# CUDA and templates: specialization declaration needed?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a templated wrapper function that calls a kernel (`__global__`) defined in a .cu file like this

```
template<typename T, class M> 
__global__ void compute_kernel(T* input, T* output, n) {
    M m;
    // compute stuff using m
};

template<typename T, class M> 
void compute(T* input, T* output, int n) {
    // ... compute blocks, threads, etc.
    compute_kernel<T,M> <<<dim_grid, dim_block>>>(input, output, n);
    // ...
};
```

and a header file to be included in host code that has only the declaration

```
template<typename T, class M> 
void compute(T* input, T* output, int n);
```

However, calling `compute()` from the host with arbitrary template parameters, the compilation fails with `undefined reference to 'void reduce(...)'` and only if I add specialization declarations to the end of the `.cu` file does the code compile:

```
template void
compute<int, Method1<int> >(int* input, int* output, int n);

template void
compute<float, Method1<float> >(float* input, float* output, int n);

template void
compute<int, Method2<int> >(int* input, int* output, int n);

template void
compute<float, Method2<float> >(float* input, float* output, int n);
```

So, is it necessary to specialize every templated function in order to make it callable from the host? (That's quite a drawback)

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: As with any template, you have to make sure that the entire template definition is visible at *every* instantiation site (unless you deliberately provide explicit instantiations).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think you are right that this is the issue. However, to separate host and device code (and also the compilation) it seems impossible to make the entire template definitions visible everywhere ...

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies. Doesn't the CUDA compiler separate the two code paths automatically? So just make an ordinary header file with the template definition of your function template and include that everywhere - what's the obstruction?

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand you correctly. Of course one can include the definition of `compute()` everywhere, as this is only host code. But `compute_kernel()` is also templated and it is not possible to include its definition everywhere, `g++` complains (mainly about the <<<...>>> in the kernel call). So I'd end up with specializations of `compute_kernel()` which doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: Why don't you compile everything with `nvcc`? That'll call the appropriate "real" compilers for you, and it'll separate the host and the device code.

Comment: Actually, I do compile everything with `nvcc`. Hmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13), not limited to CUDA.

If you have a template implementation in a .cpp or .cu file then when you compile that translation unit the compiler cannot possibly know what permutations of template parameters you will need. Therefore when you link you will get the errors.

You could put the implementation in a header file (in which case you'll need to instantiate in a .cu file since it contains CUDA) or you will have to explicitly instantiate all required permutations. If you have to do many of these then you could use a macro to instantiate all your permutations.

Comment: Thanks, this answers it. I've never really thought about non-inlined implementations of templates and kept them always in headers. So, as long as I only call the template functions from within *.cu files, I can include the full definition everywhere and no explicit instantiation is needed. This is already a great help, as (eventually) only my unit tests are going to call those functions from host code anyways.

Comment: @Tom What about using expression templates in CUDA? I have posted a question at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628470/unresolved-externals-in-cuda-expression-template-library-under-visual-studio-201), but I received no answer. For expression templates it seems not possible to instantiate all the possible permutations. Could you suggest a solution also for that?

Comment: @JackOLantern isn't this just the same problem? If it's impractical to explicitly instantiate all permutations then you should put the implementation in a header file so that it is available wherever needed. It's no different to C++ in this respect.

Comment: @Tom Yes, you are right. The paper J.M. Cohen, "Processing Device Arrays with C++ Metaprogramming", GPU Computing Gems - Jade Edition recently clarified me the whole picture. There is no difference in expression templates in C++ and CUDA. For the former, actions are taken by, e.g., classical function calls while for the latter actions are taken by `<<<...>>>` kernel launches. Thank you.